# To name a column or row at the corner of a matrix

Tags: r

Suppose that a group of people voted on weather to support a policy. Consider the two-way summarized data shown below showing the voting result of men and women.

```
  Voting Result  
Gender  Yes No  Abstain
Men     36  10  4
Women   24  30  6
```

a)  Create a matrix for the above data. Set row names for the data. Set column names for the data.

As the question described above, is that possible to make "gender" or even "Voting Result" visible when creating a matrix?

I only know how to create the basic matrix:

```
> voting.result <- rbind(c(36, 10,4),c(24,30, 6))
> rownames(voting.result) <- c("Men", "Women")
> colnames(voting.result) <- c("Yes", "No", "Abstain")
> voting.result
      Yes No Abstain
Men    36 10       4
Women  24 30       6
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible. You could do:

```
voting.result <- rbind(c(36, 10,4),c(24,30, 6))
dimnames(voting.result) <- list(Gender = c("Men", "Women"), voting = c("Yes", "No", "Abstain"))
voting.result
       voting
Gender  Yes No Abstain
  Men    36 10       4
  Women  24 30       6
```